# Why is Checkbox text not using theme font size?

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I've changed 'medium' font size with loadTheme like such:

```
loadTheme({
  fonts: {
    medium: {
      fontFamily: fonts.fontFamily,
      fontSize: fonts.fontSize.regular
    }
  }
)
```

However, the base Checkbox styles are loading font-size directly from `FontSizes` here:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/ace874ab7e56188a7d6de081915c63025def4e05/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/Checkbox/Checkbox.styles.ts#L223

I know I can override this on the component itself, but it seems like I shouldn't have to. Is this a bug? Shouldn't the component use theme font size by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Checkbox should be reading font from theme. In fact, in the fabric-7 branch, it does:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/14b1d77fc97fffb1c333a3601d62c3e30c4cf3b0/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/Checkbox/Checkbox.styles.ts#L136

Fabric 7 release is planned for May. Meanwhile you should be able to apply your own styling making use of the loadTheme call like this:

```
const checkboxStyling = (props) => {
  return {
    text: { ...props.theme.fonts.medium }
  }
}

...

<Checkbox label='test' styles={checkboxStyling} />
```

This works in the following CodePen: https://codepen.io/jasongore/pen/JVwJGO